# Managing vertical spacing before and after a specific align block

Tags: align, vertical-spacing

I looked at the similar questions but they provide answers to manage entire environments altogether. `\vspace` seems to have the local effect that I want for before the align environment. I can't find an equivalent command for below the bloc. I tried `\belowdisplayskip=0pt` but it changes the spacing for all of the align blocks.

Thank you

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
\hrule
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=x
\end{align*}
is there spacing
\vskip1cm 

\hrule \vspace{-1cm}
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=x
\end{align*} \vspace{-1cm}
is there spacing
```

As you can see the horizontal line is moved but the "is there spacing" is unmodified.

Comment: `\vspace` should work, please show a small complete document that shows the issue that you are having

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited with an example. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: it really helps if you post a test that people can run otherwise what you see depends on what you guess to add to make something to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vspace should normally be used in vertical mode, if you use it in horizontal mode it is applied after the next line break. So the use you show raises `zzz`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\hrule
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=x
\end{align*}
is there spacing
\vskip1cm 

\hrule \vspace{-1cm}
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=x
\end{align*} \vspace{-1cm}
is there spacing

zzz

\end{document}
```

Using it in vmode it is applied at that point, so raising `is there spacing`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\hrule
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=x
\end{align*}
is there spacing
\vskip1cm 

\hrule \vspace{-1cm}
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=x
\end{align*}

\vspace{-1cm}
is there spacing

zzz

\end{document}
```